# Error when I'm archiving my app to submit it to Apple store

Tags: ios, xcode

When I'm trying to make archive for my app to submit it to apple store I faced this problem and I tried a lot in appicon by removing and re-adding it again but without any result , what is the main reasons for this error ?

[image]

Comment: post your Info.plist and show where AppIcon20x20 file exist

Comment: I solved this problem thanks

Comment: @SamahAhmed You could post your own answer with a solution (feel free to do it) so it can help anybody else in this community. Please update your question with information, that NulledPointer was asking for.

Comment: @pedrouan I did that

Answer (score 0):

Only I changed all required app icon with the suitable size.